# Send user password to his email ... using php

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, css

I am having trouble sending the password of a user to his email.
everthing is going ok but the problem is, the password is md5 hashed and when I send the password to the user the hashed md5 password appears not the original one. 
I want to send the original **while keeping the password hashed**
how can I do that?

Comment: If you're not saving the original password when you hash it you can't get it back. Why are you emailing the password, if the user forgets their password have them reset it.

Comment: Eww.... Plz don't do that. Just provide a link to reset his password.

Comment: Providing link for reseting password is more appropriate.
u cannt decrypt md5'd items.

Comment: If you decrypt the `md5` algorithm, then what is purpose of using this algorithm.

Comment: Before using md5 hash you have to gather information about it that it will not decrypt. And to send user password in the mail is not a good idea, provide a link for resetting password as requested in above comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allow him to reset a password with a "special" link sent to his email. Once he clicks that link - update the data-base saying he has clicked the link(hence expire it), then let him answer a "reset" question like his DOB or his phone number he entered. or some other question.

After that, allow him to choose a new password - and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

You should never be able to recover a password in plain text after save it into the database; we hash a password exactly to make it true. If the user forgot his password, send a link to the registered e-mail to reset it and overwrite the old password on the database.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use SHA1 algorithm. In MD5 you can encode but you can not decode using any algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to decode a md5 string. So the best option is to verify user again with a security question or similar method and make him reset the password.  Besides that is a better practice as users might have used the same password in many locations.

Alternatively, YOU can reset the password for the user your self. **Simply use a random string or one of your own, then md5 in and update the password. Then you can send that random string or the string you set, to the user.**

Hope this helps